# Sorting Algorithm on hadoop framework

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, hadoop, mapreduce

I read numbers of links on internet. Here are few links [link1](http://sortbenchmark.org/YahooHadoop.pdf), [link2](http://www.slideshare.net/tungld/terasort#). But I am not able to understand. What they exactly doing. Can you pleae explain this algorithm in a simpler way.

And, yes next Question, I have one approach in my mind. Tell me wheather it is correct or not.

**Algorithm** -

Divide the whole numbers in between mappers.

**Mapper** - All mappers use basic approach (Any standard sorting algorithm, There is no use of  concept here).

**Reducer** - When all mappers are done with their task. Create a min-heap having nodes equal to number of mappers. Use this min-heap to sort the whole data. (It is easy to sort numbers of sorted lists using min-heap approach).

Is the above algorithm correct ?

Comment: I don't remember which sorting algorithm hadoop was using but at the end of the run, you have got a(or some depending on how you wrote the code) file that is sorted according to you `key`. (If this is what you want to hear)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right.

The mappers sort with a hybrid sort of Quicksort and Heapsort.

The reducers only do an n-way merge of the sorted output of the mappers.

Comment: But according to the theory, this is mandatory to make <key, value> pair in mapper. And, my mapper does not use any <key, value>

Comment: @devnull It doesn't matter which schema your records have, as long as you provide something you can sort on (or impose an order upon) there is no need for a distinction of key/value.

Comment: Ok. Can you explain please what first link(links are present above) wants to do in TeraSort ?

Comment: @devnull What do you mean by "do"?

Comment: Means, please explain the algorithm in simpler form for TeraSort module.

Comment: @devnull No idea what you are talking about. They just sort things, there is nothing special about that.

Comment: No @devnull is correct TeraSort works differently, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The links you provide are for TeraSort, so I'll try to very briefly explain it.  Though the other answer is kinda correct in that some Hadoop sorting algorithms use a combination of quicksort and -Heapsort- mergesort (I'm pretty sure you mean mergesort, not heapsort).

I think very briefly TeraSort goes like this:

- suppose we wish to sort:

2346246
7245242
8212345
1324623
4356234
9323244

then you don't need to read the entire records to see which numbers are biggest, but just the first number.  Keep this in mind when reading on.

1. Sample the data to understand the distribution of the records - get a sense of the range.
2. Select 2 bytes from each record - possibly the first 2 (like the e.g.)
3. Bucket according to these 2 bytes ensuring the buckets are 'in order' so bucket n has records that are all less than records in bucket n + 1
4. Sort each bucket
5. TADA! You have your data sorted.